# Writing to a topic within a Processor using Kafka Stream DSL

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I need to use the Kafka Sreams API alongside Processor API. I also want to write **different types of Objects** to **different topics** within my processor implementation i.e emit different object on **process** & **punctuate**. I have seen there is a [KIP-313 flatTransform](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-313%3A+Add+KStream.flatTransform+and+KStream.flatTransformValues) that would probably solve my problem.

If i use:

```
inputStream.process(processorSupplier,,)
```

Since this is a "terminating" operation (its return type is void) could I use an internal Kafka producer within my Processor. I have not seen such an implementation is this a reasonable approach are there any side effects?

Comment: Is number of different type of object (and target topics) is small and cna be define in advance? or is it change dynamically?

Comment: They are small and are known in advance

Comment: If you know the topics, the simples way is to use `KStream#branch()`.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I edited my question the main problem is that i need to emit different types of Objects within my Processor Implementation different for process/punctuate.

Comment: If understand you correctly, `flatTransform` would not help here, since it takes one input record and for each input record it emits multiple records to one downstream operator. See https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#flatTransform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-

Answer (score 1):

If you need so low level approach you can build whole topology by your own:

```java
Topology topology = builder.build();
topology.addSource("inputNode","input");
topology.addProcessor("inProcessor", InputProcessor::new, "inputNode");
topology.addSink("sink1",
    (k, v, rc) -> "topic1",
    new StringSerializer(),
    new IntegerSerializer(),
    "inProcessor");
topology.addSink("sink2",
    (k, v, rc) -> "topic2",
    new StringSerializer(),
    new StringSerializer(),
    "inProcessor");
```

InputProcessor depends on the business logic produce different types of object and pass them to different sink nodes (topics).

Sample example has logic as follow:

- if value of message can be parsed to Integer, forward it to two sink nodes (sink1, sink2), to sink1 as `Integer` to sink2 as `String`.
- if not forward message only to sink2.

```java
public class InputProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, String> {
    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        try {
            context().forward(key, Integer.parseInt(value), To.child("sink1"));
            context().forward(key, value, To.child("sink2"));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            context().forward(key, value, To.child("sink2"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. But the main point is that within the Processor  would like to build the different types according to the logic. Need to emit different types of objects in process/punctuate

Comment: @Dimitris, I've change my answer according to your update.

Comment: Thanks, this would be the way to it. But I need to implement KStream Dsl. ```inputStream.process(processorSupplier``` is terminating no Sink available. That is why i am asking if there is a way to either **implement a producer within the Processor** or return multiple types of Avro Object from a transformer?

Comment: I suppose I could wrap my Avro Object in another class And return empty set in either case.

Comment: You can use `KStream#transform()` too -- but forwarding to different children is hard at the DSL because you don't know the name of the downstream nodes. I would still recommend `branch()` -- to support different types, you can type your `KStream` as `<Object, Object>` and use `instanceof` within `branch()`.